# I am getting Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() when Navigate To Route using Href

Tags: ember.js, breeze

I am getting the error below when i navigate from my index page to my detail page detail/3. 
This works fine when I type detail/3 URL. I am using breeze with ember js

Error: Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return EntityQuery.from('Property').using(manager).execute().then(function (data) {
            return data.results;
        }).fail(queryFailed);
    }
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('add');
    this.route('detail', {path:'/detail/:detail_id'});
});

App.DetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return EntityQuery.from('Property').where("PROPERTY_ID", "==", Number(params.detail_id)).expand('RENTs').using(manager).execute().then(function (data) {
            return data.results[0];
        }).fail(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    },
    serialize: function (model) {
        return { detail_id: model.pROPERTY_ID };
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no Breeze "model library adapter" for Ember at this time. I hear tell of people who have married Breeze to Ember. You might search for that topic. It's on our wish list but not enough time yet to get it done ourselves.